# Suspicious javascript in the header on all pages (mulitiple website on the same server)

Tags: javascript, security, code-injection

Recently i discover some extra code in the headers of all pages in all websites hosted on my server. Obviously I didn't put it in myself. From what I see is some ad related scam (injection maybe). My questions is how dangerous is that?, how do I get read of it? and then how do I prevent of this never happening again?. I need help and advise on this. Thank you.

Code in question:  and :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<style>[class*="adsbygoogle"],[id*="google_ads"],[id^="gpt-unit"],div[id^="div-gpt-ad-"],img[src*="doubleclick.net"],img[src*="googlesyndication"],ins[id^="aswift_"] { display:none!important; }</style>
<script src=http://54.171.234.214/x2xmv9hn.js type='text/javascript'></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

And content of x2xmv9hn.js

```
! function() {
    "use strict";

    function a() {}
    try {
        var b = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent",
            c = window[b],
            d = function() {
                function a(a) {
                    d(a.target, e, !0)
                }

                function b(a) {
                    d(a.target, e, !1)
                }

                function c() {
                    document.addEventListener("error", a, !0), document.addEventListener("load", b, !0)
                }

                function d(a, b, c) {
                    if (a) {
                        var d = a.tagName.toLowerCase(),
                            e = b[d];
                        if (void 0 !== e) {
                            var f = a[e];
                            if ("string" == typeof f && "" !== f && 0 === f.lastIndexOf("http", 0))
                                if (c) a.style.hasOwnProperty("display") && a.setAttribute("data-adblock-preserve-display-value", a.style.display), a.style.setProperty("display", "none", "important");
                                else {
                                    var g = "";
                                    a.hasAttribute("data-adblock-preserve-display-value") && (g = a.getAttribute("data-adblock-preserve-display-value"), a.style.setProperty("display", g, ""))
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
                var e = {
                    img: "src",
                    input: "src",
                    object: "data"
                };
                return {
                    startEventListener: c
                }
            }();
        ! function() {
            var a = "attachEvent" == b ? "onmessage" : "message";
            c(a, function(a) {
                if ("lachsom" === a.data) {
                    for (var b = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe"), c = 0, d = b.length; d > c; c++) {
                        var e = b[c];
                        e && e.contentWindow && e.contentWindow === a.source && e.setAttribute("style", "display:none !important")
                    }
                    a.stopPropagation(), a.stopImmediatePropagation()
                }
            }, !1)
        }(), document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", a, !1)
    } catch (e) {
        return !1
    }
    d.startEventListener()
}();
```

Comment: What is the content of that javascript: `http://54.171.234.214/x2xmv9hn.js`?

Comment: @gmiley I tried accessing it does not work

Comment: If you have access to your logs, and/or if you can check when and by who the fie was last updated, I would start there. Does that IP belong to you, or is it some external server somewhere?

Comment: @gmiley It is an amazon ec2 instance

Comment: do you see this stuff in files at the server or in `view source` window in your browser?

Comment: Does your site use any PHP or server side code that allows users to upload files to your site in any way?

Comment: That's a good question Serge. Nita, try to determine if this is being injected by your browser, or if it is actually in the source code of the files themselves. Download the page document via FTP or somesuch, and open it locally. Does the script reference exist there, or is it only when you view source when browsing to the page from your browser?

Comment: ip 54.171.234.214 is not mine

Comment: share a link to one of your pages please

Comment: It looks like it is nothing but ad blocker related code. Likely added by a plugin you are using. Try accessing the page with a different browser. If you are currently using FireFox or Chrome, try using IE and view source with that. It will likely not be there when using a different browser.

Comment: link to one of the affected pages http://www.stopsorceryviolence.org/

Comment: How far does "your server" belong to you? Maybe your hoster injects its own ads.

Comment: I do not see this script reference in the page you pointed, so either a) you have some ad-blocking feature installed as gmiley pointed b) your browser  is compromised.

Comment: Do you use an adblocker

Comment: Websites are hosted on bluehost (i only seen this first few days ago!)

Comment: I dont' use ad blokker, should I?

Comment: @Nita your browser has been compromised

Comment: It's up to you to use or not any ad blocker. But as soon as you did not explicitly installed any ad-blocker I would urgently inspect your workstation for security threats.

Comment: Similar looking code: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/nrwjaKK-394

Comment: @Serge you don't see it ?? what do you mean in your option a?

Comment: @Nita do i see what?

Comment: i see exactly the same on all browser instaledd (ie, chrome, firefox)

Comment: Then do a virus scan of your workstation

Comment: Are you using a proxy of some kind? As @2426021684 mentioned in his answer below, you could be MITMed (Man-in-the-middled), where by your web traffic is being intercepted and altered in some way, whether beneficial or malicious. You are going to need to try several things to determine the attack vector here.

Comment: I did scan it for viruses but i will do it again, any specific software you would recommend in this case. I use avast in general, i also scanned my working station with Malwarebytes

Comment: do not use any proxy

Comment: @Nita does this happen on other websites? See if it only works on HTTP

Comment: Are you certain you are not using a proxy? Perhaps your computer has been altered without your knowledge and you have been unknowingly set to use a proxy of some kind.

Comment: I prefer Kaspersky Labs production when I need to cure an infected windows running computer. Specifically, their standalone cd-bootable version of a scanner. Due to the headache of this kind I have had with windows in the past I do not use MS production for quite a while, so have no other fresh experience

Comment: Once i view source code of other websites i do not see code in question

Comment: If you look at your installed plugins, do you have anything in there that may be related to ad blocking of some kind? Perhaps you installed some software recently that added ad blocker plugins to all of your installed browsers. Quite unlikely, but it could be possible, and would be a more simple explanation at this point. Also, when you view your site in other browser, make sure you have cleared all of your cached documents and open the site with a new browser session (if available).

Comment: Sorry, it seem that i see this code in some other websites

Comment: @Nita does that include https

Comment: I can't download the script, which seems really odd. I tried some random make an http request site and it also failed to load. Somehow the people who own the server are whitelisting your ip address.

Comment: @Nita does this appear on https sites too?

Comment: This may actually be added by your ISP, which is not unheard of. I did a little looking on that IP address you provided and it resolves to a server on amazonaws.com (ec2-54-171-234-214.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com [54.171.234.214]) which does belong to Amazon: https://whois.icann.org/en/lookup?name=amazonaws.com

Comment: @gmiley I googled fragments of the code and I only found one or two results. If it was the ISP there would be a lot more results.

Comment: @gmiley can you download the js file?

Comment: If it is injected by an ISP, it would only be visible to the end-user so it would never get indexed until someone actually copied it and posted a question like this, or save the view-source copy of the source and uploaded it, overwriting their original source code with the ad blocker injected version.

Comment: @gmiley Once we know if this happens on https, we can figure out if it is MITM or on the computer

Comment: @Nita what is your ISP

Comment: @2426021684 no I cannot access the file or the up address directly either, if I do a tracert I get timeouts after the 178.236.0.132 hop for the next 12 hops.

Comment: @gmiley I nmapped the server. HTTP does not show up. Ports 21,22,554,7070 are open.

Comment: If the computer has not been compromised, then yes https site access should not have this script injected... Unless root certificates have been added unknowingly. @Nita could you try accessing a few of the sites this has been showing up on, but use `HTTPS` instead of accessing the sites with regular `HTTP`. We need to know if it is still being injected when the site content should be encrypted from the server to your desktop. If it is still injected into the site even using HTTPS, that means either your certificates are compromised, or the code is being injected by something on your computer.

Comment: @Nita - can you go to your site using this URL: https://stopsorceryviolence.org and let us know if the script injection is still present?

Comment: @gmiley - no, is not present

Comment: i disabled all addons - no change, avast scan no infections, malewarebytes scan - all good too - malicious code stays

Comment: It is gone though when you access using HTTPS, correct? That means it is likely injected by your ISP.

Comment: well @gmiley. your theory about ISP just made me think. I'm in Papua New Guinea at the time and here everything is possible. Still if it is ISP is it any dangerous?

Comment: is there any way i can avoid this injection??

Comment: It is not likely dangerous, unless they have themselves been compromised and this is the result. Some ISPs do occasionally do this, though it would usually be something you could either disable yourself, or ask them to disable it. I would contact them and ask if it could be disabled.

Comment: Thanks @gmiley. Feel less stressed. How can i disable it. One think i know for sure is that  i do not even need to bother asking ISP in PNG on doing anything, This will simply not happen. I'm glad i have internet at all (:.

Comment: What is the name of your ISP? Perhaps they have some information on their website or elsewhere about this "feature" and possible ways to disable it yourself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112730/discussion-between-nita-and-gmiley).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you have posted so far, it seems like it is fairly innocuous. Since you say it is not actually in the source file, but only when you view source in your browser, I would say it is added by an ad blocker plugin in your browser. Try access the page using a different browser - if you are currently using FireFox, try opening the page in IE and view source via that browser. Likely the script in question will not be there in an alternative browser.

Now, when I say 'innocuous', it could be a helpful plugin. However, if you do not recall installing anything recently, I would go through my plugin list and try to determine what is adding this script. It may not be harmful at the moment, but if it is something that got installed without your knowledge, it could potentially be an attack of some kind. If it is something you did not want installed, I would find a way to remove it once you determine what plugin is adding this script.

If you do not have any plugins installed, but when accessing the same sites using HTTPS and the injected code is no longer there, the likely issue is that it is being injected by your ISP. Accessing the website via HTTPS instead of HTTP, encrypts the site from server to client preventing anything from tampering with the content. What ISP do you use? To disable this, you should contact your ISP directly and request that it be disabled for your account if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this too and came to the same conclusion that gmiley and Nita reached in the comments on the original question. It's code that Digicel Papua New Guinea is adding to non-https pages.

The service is documented [here](http://www.digicelgroup.com/tt/en/mobile/explore/other-stuff/great-deals/Shine_Ad_Control.html) for Trinidad and Tobago, so I assume Digicel PNG is doing something similar. The opt-out code didn't work for me in PNG though.

Comment: How in the world did you figure this out?? Saved my life!

Answer (score 1):

This is not happening on the server. The script and css block ads. The script is being injected in your browser or you are being MITMed. If you did not install an ad-blocker that means your computer has been compromised.

Old Answer:

This is dangerous. The forth line hides ads. The fifth lines downloads a script from an amazon ec2 instance. The script can not longer be downloaded, so we can't tell you what it did. You don't know what else the hacker did. Treat your server as compromised.

https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server#218011

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed the same thing on several of my sites that are hosted with different hosting providers, however I also noticed that this only happens when connected to certain networks.

If for example I'm connected to my home network provided by one provider I don't see these code segments injected into pages, however if I create a mobile hotspot and connect to that then browse various sites I operate I do see the code.

My conclusion is that the injection of this code is part of the ISP's systems that inject this code as part of some sort of ad blocking scheme.

Comment: Do you get it over `https://` type connections? Those are harder for ISPs to manipulate.

Comment: in my case (Papua New Guinea - Digicel) code doesn't show up over https://